# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils.clearCache()V

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, exception, spring-security

I am getting this run-time error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils.clearCache()V
```

And part of stack trace:

```
Caused By: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils.clearCache()V
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.resetCommonCaches(AbstractApplicationContext.j
ava:915)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:575)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:409
)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
```

Here are my Spring dependencies in the pom.xml:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Here is `${springframework.version}`:

```
<properties>
    <springframework.version>5.0.4.RELEASE</springframework.version>
</properties>
```

The important part is that I am only getting this run-time error when I add any of the `org.springframework.security` dependencies; I do not get this error when I don't include any of them.

Here is output of `mvn dependency:tree`:

```
+- ora.common.logging:common-logging:jar:1.2.0:system
+- ognl:ognl:jar:3.2.6:compile
|  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.20.0-GA:compile
+- org.apache.hivemind:hivemind-framework:jar:2.0-alpha-1:compile
|  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.3:compile
|  \- jboss:javassist:jar:3.4.ga:compile
+- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:provided
+- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.2.16.Final:compile
|  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.1.Final:compile
|  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
|  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
|  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.1.Final:compile
|  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.3.Final:compile
|  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.0:compile
|  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
|  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.1.Final:compile
+- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.0.5.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.0.5.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.0.5.RELEASE:compile
|  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.0.5.RELEASE:compile
+- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
+- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
+- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
+- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
+- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
|  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
+- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
|  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
+- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:2.0.2.RELEASE:compile
|  \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.0.2.RELEASE:compile
+- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
+- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
+- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.0:compile
+- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.0:compile
+- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.0:compile
+- org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.jpa:jar:2.6.4:compile
|  +- org.eclipse.persistence:javax.persistence:jar:2.1.1:compile
|  +- org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.asm:jar:2.6.4:compile
|  +- org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.antlr:jar:2.6.4:compile
|  +- org.glassfish:javax.json:jar:1.0.4:compile
|  +- org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql:jar:2.6.4:compile
|  \- org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.core:jar:2.6.4:compile
+- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
+- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.7:compile
+- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:jar:4.1:compile
+- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
|  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
+- org.hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:2.3.4:test
+- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.0.1:provided
+- javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:jar:2.1:provided
+- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.10:compile
+- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.2:compile
|  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.2:compile
+- org.mapstruct:mapstruct-jdk8:jar:1.2.0.Final:compile
+- org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics:jar:1.11.1:compile
|  +- org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics-runtime:jar:1.11.1:compile
|  +- org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics-tools:jar:1.11.1:compile
|  |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.2:compile
|  |  |  \- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
|  |  \- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.7:compile
|  \- com.google.code.javaparser:javaparser:jar:1.0.11:compile
+- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.8.13:compile
+- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.13:compile
\- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:2.10.4:compile
```

Comment: Have you tried `mvn dependency:tree`?

Comment: This method was added in Spring 4.3. You must have an old spring-core module somewhere on your classpath. Try like `mvn dependency:tree` to see what brings it in. Also Spring Security and Spring Framework are not always on the same release cycle, so it may not be a good idea to use the same version variable for them.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by changing the version of spring security dependencies to:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Yes, I don't remember the specific documentation, but Spring-Security and Spring Framework are on different release numbers and cause headaches. You need to find the Spring Security dependency that is compatible with your Spring Framework version.

Comment: @Compass And do you know how to do that besides trial and error?

Comment: To see which version of Spring Core the security module builds with, check the reference docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/ , 5.0.5 here targets 5.0.6 core, for example. Mentions something about a bom that you could possibly use to get around this annoyance, though I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 0):

For me works on:

```
        <spring.version>5.0.8.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring-security.version>5.0.7.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
```